# Ruby on rails Queing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

There are 2 apis exposed for customer and merchant.. Both merchant and customer will hit their respective api with *same transaction id* .. Whoever comes first i should create the record in db with transaction id and merchant details (if merchant comes first) and second if customer comes i should update the record with customer details with transaction id where merchant has created the record.

How can i handle it by accepting 10,000 request hits at once. It should reply back without any issue ? Please let me know how can we implement in `rails` and is it possible or not.

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I'm skidish giving this as an answer, but it sounds like you just need is a lock.  Alter your table to include a column called 'owned_by' (or something similar).

Whenever your instance needs to modify a record, have it issue an update like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET owned_by = IF(owned_by IS NULL, 'uniq_id', owned_by) WHERE id = 1;
```

The IF statement keeps it from stealing the lock if it was locked in between checks.

Then requery for the row, and if the uniq_id is set to the current threads uniq_id, then you know you are safe to write, otherwise have it sleep in increments and requery until the records lock frees.  If something can be done without a lock, just have it ignore that field.  Work flow could look something like this (sudo code):

```
def uniq_id
  rand() #probably want something better here
end

def trylock_row
  "UPDATE table_name SET owned_by = IF(owned_by IS NULL, '#{uniq_id}', owned_by) WHERE id = #{id};"
end

def release_lock
  "UPDATE table_name SET owned_by = IF(owned_by == '#{uniq_id}', NULL, owned_by) WHERE id = #{id};"
end

def reget_row
  "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = #{id}"
end

def issue_update something
  r = self
  while(r.owned_by != uniq_id){
    if r.owned_by.nil?
      trylock_row
      r = reget_row
      break if r.owned_by == uniq_id
    end
    sleep(0.25) #arbitrary, keep it small
    r = reget_row
  }
  #issue_updates
  release_lock #Really should be in a ensure block just in case
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I will provide an alternative way to handle this.

As Camway mentioned in his answer, locking is one way to do it. Here are some extra resources:

http://thelazylog.com/understanding-locking-in-rails-activerecord/

https://www.leighhalliday.com/avoid-race-conditions-with-postgres-locks

Another way to handle that would be using database level constraint. While the Rails level race condition might cause your data integrity to fail, on the database level, records are still inserted one after another (which is one of the reasons why write is slower than read).

So you can simply add a unique index constraint on one of the fields. Since you didn't describe how customers and merchants match the transaction_id, I can't tell which field to add the constraint on. But you could have something like this:

```
def find_or_create
  # pseudocode here
  transaction = Transaction.find_by_condition(...)
  return transaction if transaction

  Transaction.create!(...)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  log_error
  retry
end
```

I am using this in production and we serve millions of db transactions without issue. And the rescue block will usually only get executed a few times since most of the time you will find the record and return it right away.